# Get bash to respect quotes when word splitting subshell output

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have a command that outputs some parameters that I want to pass to another command. However, when I run the command in a subshell, the output is subject to [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) unless I quote the whole thing, in which case it is a single word.

I want the subshell output to have words split, but I want the word splitting to respect quotes, and it does not. Is there some way (other than `eval`) to get the subshell output split into words but respecting quotes?

#### Details

Given the `args` command defined as

```sh
#!/bin/sh -
printf "%d args:" "$#"
printf " <%s>" "$@"
echo
```

I can run

```bsh
$ args 'foo bar' 'one two'
2 args: <foo bar> <one two>
```

but I cannot find a way to get a subshell to pass 2 args like that.

```bsh
$ echo "\"'foo bar'\" 'one two'"
"'foo bar'" 'one two'
$ args $(echo "\"'foo bar'\" 'one two'")
4 args: <"'foo> <bar'"> <'one> <two'>
$ args "$(echo "\"'foo bar'\" 'one two'")"
1 args: <"'foo bar'" 'one two'>
```

Of course, I can use `eval`

```bsh
$  eval args $(echo "'foo bar' 'one two'")
2 args: <foo bar> <one two>
```

but `eval` is dangerous and introduces all kinds of other scary possibilities for things to go wrong. I do not want parameter expansion or globbing to happen again, etc. I just want word splitting to respect the quotes. Is there really no way to do that in `bash`?

Comment: Why do you combine double quotation marks, then single quotation marks and finally double quotation marks again? Your code example: `args $(echo "\"'foo bar'\" 'one two'")` is fail. Try the following syntax: `args $(echo "'foo bar' 'one two'")` or `args $(echo '"foo bar" "one two"')` or `args $(echo "\"foo bar\" \"one two\"")`. Just insert a backslash ```\``` before a special character. The question may have already been answered for you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347268/bash-printf-how-do-i-output-x-and-f-within-double-quotes

Comment: Why do you want quotation marks? They are understood as parameters and not as strings, so if you use `args`, quotes don't matter.

Comment: @s3n0 The `echo` command is a simplified example of a complex command I want to run that produces quoted output. I used various kinds of quoting in my example to show that no kind of quoting does what I want. Also note that each version of the command line you included in your comment produces different output, yet none of them are what I want.

Comment: "eval" sometimes are more suitable to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bash really doesn't have a good way to parse a string into substrings, while respecting quotes. Whether it's coming from a command expansion (that is, `$( )` -- what I think you're calling a subshell) or a plain variable expansion (`$varname`).

- If you double-quote the expansion, no splitting at all is done.
- If you don't double-quote the expansion, it splits on whitespace, but doesn't pay attention to quotes or escapes. It also tries to expand anything that looks like a filename wildcard, which can cause comedy and/or tragedy.
- If you use `eval` on a double-quoted expansion, it parses *all* shell syntax, including other command and variable expansions, redirects, multiple commands with `;` or `&`, etc. Lots of opportunity for bad results here.
- If you use `eval` on a non-quoted expansion, you get the split-on-whitespace-and-expand-wildcards effect, *followed* by a regular full parsing. Pretty much everything can go wrong here.
- `read -a` is the best of a bad lot. It completely fails at respecting quotes, but at least it doesn't expand filename wildcards.

So bash itself can't do this. But `xargs` can -- its default split-into-words parsing respects quotes and escapes, so depending on the situation you might be able to use it directly:

```
$ echo "\"'foo bar'\" 'one two'" | xargs args
2 args: <'foo bar'> <one two>
```

There are a couple of potential problems with this: For one thing, depending on how much output there is, `xargs` might decide to split them between multiple runs of the command. You can adjust this to some extent with its `-n`, `-s`, and `-x` options, but it's not entirely satisfactory.

Another possible problem is that if the command is actually a shell function, complex command, or builtin you want to execute in the current shell, this won't work. You can adapt it, but it's messy; you need to use `xargs printf '%s\0'` to convert to a null-delimited sequence of strings, then use a `while IFS= read -r -d ''` loop to convert that to a bash array, and then finally you can do something with the array:

```
$ argarray=()
$ while IFS= read -r -d '' arg; do argarray+=("$arg"); done < <(echo "\"'foo bar'\" 'one two'" | xargs printf '%s\0')
$ args "${argarray[@]}"
2 args: <'foo bar'> <one two>
```

Note that this uses a process substitution with `<( )`. This is a bash-only feature, and won't even work when bash is in sh-emulation mode. So you must start your script with an explicit bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) (and don't override the shebang by running the script with `sh scriptname`).

Comment: That `xargs` trick made my day...

Comment: Even the `xargs` trick didn't help. That's an extremely ugly wart. It basically means you can't use flags generated by a command as there's no sane way to split them into words the way a literal would be. There's also the second method; but I'm still angry how something like this doesn't have a simpler way...

Comment: @Noein If you have a situation where this doesn't work, it might be worth asking a new question with the specifics that complicate your situation.